# script.js код, реализующий кнопку «Подробнее» для просмотра статьи

Tags: javascript, html, css

я совсем ещё зеленый в этой теме,подскажите пожалуйста.Как реализовать кнопку подробнее через js ,я хочу сделать так: overflow: hidden;  при нажатии заменить на overflow: visible;
Возможно ли это как то сделать через js?
(Этот код не работает,возможно я неправильно обращаюсь,или же вообще так делать нельзя?)

```js
  var info=document.getElementsByClassName("button_info")
  var text_info=document.getElementsByClassName("text_none")
  info.onclick = function () {
    document.getElementByClassName('text_none').style.overflow="visible"; 
  }
```

```css
.text_none {
  max-height: 150px;
  max-width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden; 
  border: 1px solid black;
}             
.button_info{
  background-color:  darkcyan;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button_info">Показать всё содержимое статьи:</div>
<div class="text_none"> Текст,который будет не вмещаться  в рамки <br>
  Текст,который вмещается в рамки<br>
  Текст,который вмещается в рамки<br>
  Текст,который вмещается в рамки<br>
  Текст,который вмещается в рамки<br>
  Текст,который вмещается в рамки<br>
  Текст,который вмещается в рамки<br>
  Текст,который вмещается в рамки<br>
  Текст,который  не вмещался в рамки<br>
  Текст,который  не вмещался в рамки<br>
  Текст,который  не вмещался в рамки<br>
  Текст,который  не вмещался в рамки<br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не очень понял, что это "Текст,который будет не вмещаться  в рамки".
Но в остальном можно использовать класс модификатор, к примеру "more". Который по кнопке будет добавлять необходимые вам стили и при повторном клике возвращать обратно. Надеюсь правильно понял вопрос.

```js
let info=document.querySelector(".button_info")
let text_info=document.querySelector(".text_none")
info.onclick = function ()
{
   text_info.classList.toggle('more')   
}
```

```css
.text_none {
  max-height: 150px;
  max-width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden; 
  border: 1px solid black;
}         
.text_none.more {
  max-height: none;  
  overflow: visible;
  
}  

.button_info {
  background-color:  darkcyan;
  color: white;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="button_info">Показать всё содержимое статьи:</div>
<div class="text_none">
  Текст,который будет не вмещаться  в рамки <br>
  Текст,который вмещается в рамки<br>
  Текст,который вмещается в рамки<br>
  Текст,который вмещается в рамки<br>
  Текст,который вмещается в рамки<br>
  Текст,который вмещается в рамки<br>
  Текст,который вмещается в рамки<br>
  Текст,который вмещается в рамки<br>
  Текст,который  не вмещался в рамки<br>
  Текст,который  не вмещался в рамки<br>
  Текст,который  не вмещался в рамки<br>
  Текст,который  не вмещался в рамки<br>
</div>
```

Comment: Мне бы на чистой жабе..

Comment: @Dreams чище некуда )

Comment: а это разве не jquery?

Comment: @Dreams нет, тру ванилла ) А что вас смутило?

Comment: понял,спасибо!буду сейчас разбираться!

Comment: @Dreams ctrl+f5 ?

Comment: Извините за множество вопросов,но все же, что делает classList.toggle? Он заменяет класс .text_none на  .text_none.more?

Comment: кажется понял,он добавляет класс,если его нет,и удаляет-если есть.

Comment: Да, как раз пытался пояснить в ответе. Ну раз разобрались, хорошо.